# How to speed up Fetching Google Place and Photos

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-places-api

I currently have the following code to fetch matching Google Places according to a received query as shown below:

```
 async function searchGoogleBusiness(req, res) {
        let { name } = req.query;
        const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
        const searchUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=`;
        try {
            let { data } = await axios.get(`${searchUrl}${name}&key=${apiKey}`)
            let { status, error_message, results } = data;
            if (status === 'OK') {
                let businessResults = [];
                if ((results ?? []).length > 0) {
                    for (let business of results) {
                        let businessDetails = {
                            ....
                        }
                        if ((business.photos ?? []).length > 0) {
                            let { width = 1200, height = 1200, photo_reference } = business.photos[0];
                            let photoUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=${photo_reference}&sensor=false&maxheight=${height}&maxwidth=${width}&key=${apiKey}`
                            try {
                                let businessPhotoResponse = await axios.get(photoUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
                                let imageBuffer = businessPhotoResponse.data;
                                let base64Image = Buffer.from(imageBuffer, 'binary').toString('base64');
                                businessDetails.photo = `data:${businessPhotoResponse.headers['content-type']};base64,${base64Image}`;
                            } catch (e) {
                                businessDetails.photo = business.icon;
                            }
                        } else {
                            businessDetails.photo = business.icon;
                        }
                        businessResults.push(businessDetails);
                    }
                }
               ...//Omitted
            }
            ...//Omitted
        } catch (e) {
          ...//Omitted
        }
    }
```

As you can immediately notice, the function takes forever to return when the results are more than 5 and the reason is because I'm looping through each business to make another api call to fetch each photo.

I don't like this approach at all.

This idea of making another network call using photoReferences is really affecting my site speed and basically just makes my users angry.

Is there no way to automatically fetch the photo urls along just in the first request?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the [Places Library for Maps Javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos)? Or do you really need to use the Places API server side only? Maps Javascript actually have a built in Places API in case you are not aware.

Comment: Yea, I need to use the Places API server side only